# Using gdal.Warp() and gdal.warpOptions() of GDAL Python API

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, vrt

According to http://gdal.org/python/ the `gdal.Warp()` and `gdal.WarpOptions()` can be used to warp image from HDF to GeoTIFF format by geolocation arrays, but there is no any example. It would not run, even I try to use `.vrt` file including lat/lon and database layers sites.

the VRT file:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
  <VRTDataset rasterXSize="" rasterYSize="">
  <Metadata domain="GEOLOCATION">
    <MDI key="LINE_OFFSET">0</MDI>
    <MDI key="LINE_STEP">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="PIXEL_OFFSET">0</MDI>
    <MDI key="PIXEL_STEP">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="SRS">GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]</MDI>
    <MDI key="X_BAND">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="X_DATASET">HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"C:/Users/TLQ/Desktop/11/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.hdf":38', '[2030x1354] Longitude (32-bit floating-point)</MDI>
    <MDI key="Y_BAND">1</MDI>
    <MDI key="Y_DATASET">HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"C:/Users/TLQ/Desktop/11/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.hdf":37', '[2030x1354] Latitude (32-bit floating-point)</MDI>
  </Metadata>
  <VRTRasterBand dataType="Float32" band="1">
    <SimpleSource>
      <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"C:/Users/TLQ/Desktop/11/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.hdf":45', '[2030x1354] 1km Band 3 Path Radiance (16-bit integer)</SourceFilename>
      <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
    </SimpleSource>
  </VRTRasterBand>
</VRTDataset>
```

the code:

vrt

```
file = "C:/test/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.hdf"
ds = gdal.Open(file)
subDatasets = ds.GetSubDatasets()
gdal.WarpOptions(geoloc=True, format='GTiff')
gdal.Warp("C:/test/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.tif",'C:/test/tel.vrt',\           options=gdal.WarpOptions(geoloc=True, format='GTiff'))
```

Comment: There are some usage examples in the GDAL autotest suite https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/utilities/test_gdalwarp_lib.py.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Late, but better than never :) https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html - useful link for organizing gdal operations in your code

Answer (score 14):

You have two options here:

1. Create a `gdal.WarpOptions` object and pass it to `gdal.Warp` as the `options` argument, just as you are doing (although you can skip the fourth line as you are creating the same object on the fifth line).
2. Create a dictionary with the arguments and pass it as keyword arguments to `gdal.Warp`. For example:

```
kwargs = {'format': 'GTiff', 'geoloc': True}
ds = gdal.Warp('C:/test/MYD09.A2011093.0410.006.2015217030905.tif', 'C:/test/tel.vrt', **kwargs)
del ds
```

Check the `gdal.WarpOptions` [documentation](https://gdal.org/api/python/utilities.html#osgeo.gdal.WarpOptions) to see what other keywords you can pass, as their names slightly differ from the `gdalwarp` command line utility.

Comment: The link to the documentation of `gdal.WarpOptions` is broken, but you can display them with `help(gdal.WarpOptions)`

Comment: You can get the WarpOptions here https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.Warp