# How to use GDAL from within a Python program

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a fairly complex Python program that needs to use a single command of GDAL. Currently I'm using `os.popen` to call the command `gdalwarp` from Python. This works, but is an ugly approach, so I'd prefer to use GDAL from within the Python program. However I'm a bit overwhelmed by [the documentation](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#Warp) and I have found no simple example I can use to tackle my problem.

The command I'm using is something like:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -co compress=none -of Gtiff -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te -180.02250000 -90.02250000 179.97750000 90.02250000 -tr 0.045 0.045 *.tiff output.tiff
```

How can I reproduce the behaviour of this command with Python calls to the GDAL library?

Comment: Look at `gdal.Warp` https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278627/how-do-use-gdal-warp-and-gdal-warpoptions-of-python-api

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first convert all tif input as a single vrt, then run the `gdal.Warp`

```py
from pathlib import Path
from osgeo import gdal

vrt_name= 'input.vrt'
tifs = [str(p) for p in Path('.').glob('*.tiff')]
my_vrt = gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_name, tifs)
my_vrt = None

ds_input = gdal.OpenEx(vrt_name, gdal.OF_RASTER)
ds = gdal.Warp('output.tif', ds_input, options="-overwrite -co compress=none -of Gtiff -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te -180.02250000 -90.02250000 179.97750000 90.02250000 -tr 0.045 0.045")
del ds
del ds_input
```

You can have 4 syntax for options (3rd and more args). The way to provide options is similar to [Issue to convert from PostgreSQL input to GPKG using Python GDAL API function gdal.VectorTranslate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/397023/issue-to-convert-from-postgresql-input-to-gpkg-using-python-gdal-api-function-gd) except you need to provide a `gdal.WarpOptions`

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Just a minor comment. My call to `gdal.BuildVRT` did not produce any output file. Instead, I was able to use the `my_vrt` object instead of `'input.vrt'`. I'm not sure if this is how it is supposed to work, but it does the job and is a cleaner solution, as it does not write temporary files in disk.

Comment: Intrigued by your last paragraph, I'm now trying to use a dictionary instead of a long string to setup warp. Unfortunately I can't find the way to do it. I posted a new question here in case you want to follow up. 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398223/how-to-remap-gdal-options-from-string-version-to-a-dictionary-version