# gdal.WarpOptions not accepting srcBands argument?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp

Defining as follows:

```
warpoptions = gdal.WarpOptions(format = 'GTiff', outputType = gdal.GDT_Float32, srcBands = [1], dstBands = [1], dstSRS = 'EPSG:4326', dstNodata = 0, resampleAlg = 'cubicspline', width = w_width, height = w_height)
```

But when I go to warp: `nc_w_dataset = gdal.Warp('/vsimem/inmem_w_ds.tif', nc_procd_t_dataset, options = warpoptions)`

I get the following: TypeError: **WarpOptions() got an unexpected keyword argument 'srcBands'**?

According to gdal.org: "**osgeo.gdal.WarpOptions**(options=None, format=None, **srcBands=** None,....". Am I missing something?

Comment: Does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278627/using-gdal-warp-and-gdal-warpoptions-of-gdal-python-api help?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The newer link to the warp options definitions is: https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html (and then search for gdal.WarpOptions. Their layout makes browsing difficult, and their lack of examples is frustrating), and they definitely list srcBands as an available warp option in the python API. Guessing it's a formatting issue, but I have no idea what a working example looks like!

Comment: Could it be a version issue? could you please share a complete minimal example, including how you import osgeo.gdal?

Comment: The GDAL autotests are often usable as examples. See https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/alg/warp.py. srcBands is new to GDAL version 3.7 https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html that was released one month ago. Do you have that version or current trunk version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that these options were added in the latest release v3.7.0

https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/v3.7.0/NEWS.md

> Utilities

> gdalwarp: add -srcband (aliased to -b) and -dstband options

Comment: Well looky there! LOL - I am new to python, and am used to finding OLD libraries/code samples, it never even occurred to me that I wasn't current! Thank you @OliverLopez, that is indeed the issue!